# How do I change input type date format to mm/dd/yy?

Tags: html, date, format

I currently have an input type="date" and the default format is mm/dd/yyyy, but I want the format to be mm/dd/yy. How can you change the format of a date input?

```
 Date:<input type="date" id="date" name="date" value="mm/dd/yy" required/>
```

Comment: Only wanting to format the display in my input to mm/dd/yy, not changing the backend

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible with plain HTML. You'll have to use a hacky JS solution like this:

```js
var text = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
var date = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
date.addEventListener("change", e=>{
    split = date.value.split("-");
  text.value = split[1]+"-"+split[2]+"-"+split[0].substring(2);
})
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 113px;
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
<input type="text" readonly>
```